# I'm returning a defaultdict(list), but randomly choosing between the two, why does it return nothing sometimes?

Tags: python

```
output = ""
numberList = [0, 1]
print(random.choice(numberList))
if(random.choice(numberList) == 0): 
   if len(slots) > 0:
          output = templates[state][0].replace("<num_classes>", str(slots[0][1]))
   else:
          output = templates[state][0]

elif(random.choice(numberList) == 1):
    if len(slots) > 0:
        output = templates2[state][0].replace("<num_classes>", str(slots[0][1]))
    else:
        output = templates2[state][0]

return output
```

[expected answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhcCN.png)
[sometimes get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWDlX.png)

Sometimes it returns nothing or no dictionary... Why?

Comment: what is slots? and templates?

Answer (score 1):

With

```
elif(random.choice(numberList) == 1)
```

you will *again* choose a *brand new* random number. And if that isn't `1` then there's no `else` that will set `output`.

Instead of `elif` you should have a plain `else`.